# Swift - How can I detect swipe gesture distance to give up?

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

How Can Instagram handle swipe gesture distance while swipe back (pop navigation process). For example, If it is not long distance, you can give up swipe back and then return again old view.

I wonder this, If someone explain It would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The gesture recognizer does not detect the distance per se.
Rather, you would move the view with the gesture recognizer, and then, when the gesture ends, decide whether the view has moved beyond a certain point, and take action accordingly.
 So, in a simple example you might test whether the view had moved more than half way off the screen:
if so, you continue moving it and segue to another view;
if not, you set up an animation to take the view back to its starting point.
Hope that helps.

You might want to check out:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views which explains this methodology in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

Using the UIGestureRecognizer is absolutely fine. You might want to take look at the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1619996-touchesmoved 
This method returns the UITouch and again from the Apple docs you can see that this UITouch represents the location, size, movement, and force of a finger on the screen for a particular event.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this func to count distance between two points:

```
//Distance
extension CGPoint {
    func distanceCount(_ point: CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return abs(CGFloat(hypotf(Float(point.x - x), Float(point.y - y))))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let myDistance = p1.distanceCount(p2) //p1 is firstTouch and p2 is when user stops touching.
```

Then you can make something like

```
    if distance < SomeValue {
   //Some code
 }
```

Hope it will help you a little bit.